# Frequency of Intra versus interprocess context switching

Tags: kernel, scheduling, multithreading

In a book I'm reading (from 2013) it says that, in the Linux Kernel, intraprocess switching is much more cheaper than interprocess switching, I guess, because the switching in a same CPU between two threads of a same process saves you the cost of switching page tables.

So switching between two threads/tasks of a same process is cheaper than switching between unrelated tasks.

Do the linux kernel tries to increase somehow (besides process affinity) the likehood of intraprocess switching for that gain in performance?

In case it's not, how often that it happens? Is it an argument to say that threads are a good thing because they are cheap to switch, if in practice intraprocess switching rarely happens?

Comment: "Is it an argument to say that threads are a good thing because they are cheap to switch, if in practice intraprocess switching rarely happens?" Why would that make it not an argument? Just because a good thing might happen less often doesn't make it less good. It just means we should try to make the good thing happen more often.